# Strange error upon insert in SQL

Tags: select, null, insert, ssms

This process is part of one where I take fields from a 96 column table and place them in a 26 column table (directory). Yrqtr is a field in the table, equi.

I am getting the following error message. I am only confused because yrqtr is not in either statement. any ideas why this one is coming up?

Msg 515, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'yrqtr', table 'wid27.dbo.directory'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

```
   Insert into dbo.directory(state,account,unit,name1,name2,address1,address2,city,st,zip,zipext,addressty,geo1,geo2,telephone,employment,ownership,naicscode,siccode,area)

   Select state,account,unit,name1,name2,address1,address2,city,st,zip,zipext,addressty,geo1,geo2,telephone,employment,ownership,naicscode,siccode,area
   From dbo.equi Where something !=2
```

Comment: Did my answer help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be a constraint in your table schema.

If you look at your schema you will most likely see `NOT NULL` next to the column definition.  If you remove it, you will be able to insert.   However, you could be breaking someone else's intentional schema design and inserting a null value could lead to bugs.

More information:

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_notnull.asp

Comment: @Taylor_Ackley. Your answer did help. However, why does the error mention a field that is not mentioned in either statement?

Comment: Because if NULLS aren't allowed for the column, but it's in the table then its a violation of the constraint.